# how to detect if tfilestream has been freed?

Tags: delphi, filestream, tfilestream

is there a way to see if an instace of tfile stream is being used?
for example if i declare FS of type tfilestream,write buffer to it and 
finally free the stream using tfilestream.free can i check something 
like:

```
if 
tfilestream.NotActive
then
 //code
if tfilestream.beingused then
 //code
if tfilestream.free = true then
    //code
```

**active** and **beingused** methods do not exists for real nor can we test **tfilestream.free = true**  just making this up to give idea what i am trying to ask

Comment: There's really no way to detect if an object has been freed or not, since the memory can get reused by other objects.  The correct way to do it is to mostly not reuse object references after they're freed, and when you do need to, use FreeAndNil, like Robert pointed out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't do it in the way you expect.   But you and do it with `FreeAndNil()`

```
var
  FS : TFileStream;
begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create(...);
  try
   // Do Work with TFileSTream 
  finally 
   FreeAndNil(FS);
  end;

  // For some reason you need to check FS is freed.

  if not Assigned(FS) then
  begin
   // Stream was freed.
  end;
end;
```