# Hang on SomeObject.Free. Check if object is already free in FPC?

Tags: delphi, free, freeze, fpc

if if have an object (in my case TJSONData) and I want to free this object the programm flow sometimes hangs at this position. I already have a construct like the following in my code but it seems to not fit the case some times:

```
if Assigned(MyRecord.MyJSONData) then
begin
  MyRecord.MyJSONData.Free;
end;
```

I can reproduce this behavior in tests if I try to free an object two times. In my program this should normally not happen but now my real question:

Is there a way to check if the object is already free? Or do I need to use also FreeAndNil();?

Comment: This may help [check if freed already 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345905/how-to-detect-if-tfilestream-has-been-freed) and [check if freed already 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113504/bad-reference-to-an-object-already-freed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The Assigned function checks to see if a reference is **not nil**. It
>   returns True if not nil, and False if nil.

Obviously when you free the object and do not set reference to nil it will pass on next Assigned check (reference <> nil) and will be attempted to free again. But the reference (pointer) is already dangling (pointing to freed or worse, changed, memory).

Generally you should set your references to **nil** or better - use FreeAndNil function. This way each time you will want to access the freed object it will be nil and thats your check.

Answer (score -1):

There was a large thread in Delphi forum (the tread that eventually crushed the forum) about FreeAndNil.

Common point was that for 95% of tasks you should not *check* if an object is alive, you should *know* it beforehand and architect the program so that you always know and never need those checks.

Some survived or revived links are at http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/01/16/verity_stob_sons_of_khan_2011/print.html and at https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=413796

Comment: That discussion was about something else (setting variables to nil). This question is about a member (or field) of a class, where the field never goes out of scope as long as it's parent class exists. In this case, `FreeAndNil` (or setting it to `nil` manually) is an absolute necessity. This is not the same as those discussions; the two uses are totally different things.